# Bash, If file is empty leave script if not continue

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

the first command in my bash script is a grep from an existing file for errors.
EX:

```
cat /usr/local/avamar/var/ddrmaintlogs/ddrmaint.log | grep "hfscheck-finish Backup directory missing for backup" > PartialBackups
cat PartialBackups | sed -n -e 's#^.*cur/ ##p' >P2                                          
cat P2 | sed 's#/# / /#g' > P3                                                              
cat P3 | awk {'print $1'} >> S1                                                              
cat P3 | awk {'print $3'} >> S2
```

if newfile is empty (PartialBackups File) i want to exit the script, if not i want the script to continue

how can i do that?

Comment: You're approach is wrong, the whole of the script you posted should be a single call to awk. If you [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output and tag it with awk then we can help you. Also, where did you get the idea that the **script delimiters** (`'`) should go **inside** the script `{'print $1'}` instead of around it `'{print $1}'`? I've seen a couple of people do that and I'm just curious where that idea is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

Put the `grep` in an `if` statement.

```
if ! grep -err /file >> newfile; then
    exit
fi
```

`newfile` may or may not be empty--you are appending to a possibly non-empty file to begin with--but `grep` will have a non-zero exit status if it doesn't *add* anything to the file.

Comment: I'd attach `>> newFile` directly to the `grep` command; otherwise, this looks like the best answer.

Comment: Now I'm trying to figure out why I thought it needed to be on the `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
if ! [ -s "/file" ];then
    exit
fi
```

or shorter with less obvious syntax

```
test -s "/file" && exit
```

`test -s` tests if a file exists and has non-zero size. The second syntax is exploiting, that binary operators only evaluate as much as needed, so a positive return value from `test` prevents `exit` from running, as the expression would be false anyway.